# Need help on query performance

Tags: mysql, query-performance

Today I am facing on strange issue I have below query. When i run this query it is taking long time. E.g. if i put only "where  w2.cdate between '2018-01-01 00:00:00' and '2018-10-31 23:59:59'" or only "s2.status='NEW'" then it gives immediate result but if i put both conditions together then it takes time. My both "cdate" and "status" columns are indexed. What could be reason behind this how can i find that.

```
select w2.id from status s2
  inner join order w2 on s2.warenkorb__id=w2.id 
    where  w2.cdate between '2018-01-01 00:00:00' and '2018-10-31 23:59:59' and  s2.status='NEW'
```

Eplain result with all conditions
[image: Explain Result with all condition]

Explain result with date condtion
[image]

Comment: share `explain` statement result

Comment: Consider an index on `order (cdate, id)`

Comment: Thank you MadhurBhaiya and tim-biegeleisen I dont have index alter access right i will try this hope it should work.

Comment: Whatever the solution, the fact that the query runs fast with either condition but slow with both of them combined shows that MySQL's optimizer is doing a bad job here. An additional restriction must of course not make a query slower. Maybe the DBMS makes wrong assumption as to the data in the tables. You may want to look up the docs on how to keep optimizer statistics up-to-date.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the difference in `EXPLAIN` statement results, that the case using all the conditions is not able to `Using Index`.

You can add the following two composite indexes and test:

1. `(warenkorb__id, status)` on the `status` table.
2. `(id, cdate)` on the `order` table.

[`ALTER TABLE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html) queries would be the following:

```
ALTER TABLE status ADD INDEX(warenkorb__id, status);

ALTER TABLE order ADD INDEX(id, cdate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data model allows for multiple statuses per order. So to get the query straight I would select the ID from the order table and look up the status in the `WHERE`clause:

```
select id
from `order`
where cdate >= date '2018-01-01'
  and cdate <  date '2018-11-01'
  and id in (select warenkorb__id from status where status = 'NEW');
```

(In other DBMS one might use `INTERSECT` instead, but MySQL doesn't feature this.)

Now consider two approaches:

1. The DBMS selects the statuses first in order to get the orders.
2. The DBMS selects the orders first and looks up their statuses.

For case 1 you'd want:

```
create index idx1 on status (status, warenkorb__id);
```

and an index on order(id) which you should already have. Or even provide a covering index:

```
create index idx2 on `order` (id, cdate);
```

For case 2 you'd want:

```
create index idx3 on `order` (cdate, id);
create index idx4 on status (warenkorb__id, status);
```

Create those four indexes, look at the execution plan and drop the indexes that the DBMS doesn't use.

Answer (score 0):

These should work well, regardless of which table the Optimizer decides to start with:

```
w2:  INDEX(cdate, id)
s2:  INDEX(status, warenkorb__id)
```

The stated order of columns is important.  (I don't think Thorsten's extra pair of indexes helps any.)

Questions about the Schema:

- Is `id` the `PRIMARY KEY` of `w2`?  (Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` so this, and other questions, aren't needed.)
- Are the two tables in a 1:1 relationship?  That is *usually* not a good design.  It seems that `status` could be in `w2`.